# If I drop from Gold to Silver in Ranked, which splash art border will I receive at the end of Season 3?

Tags: league-of-legends

At the beginning of Season 3, I was placed into the `Gold League, Division V`. Currently I am at `Silver League, Division I` due to inactivity.

When Season 3 ends, which summoner splash art border will I receive? I am not sure, but I believe that in Season 2 if you entered a higher league you got the border, regardless of whether you dropped back down or not. If that is the case, then I should have a gold border for the next season.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Season 1, the reward was colored borders around summoner icons.  The rank you had at the end of the season [determined your reward](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?p=13402751).

For Season 2, the reward was colored borders around champion portraits in the loading screen.  The highest rank you had attained during the last two months of the season [determined your reward](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=2568236).

For Season 3, the reward will be summoner icons, loading screen borders, and medals.  The highest rank you attain at the end of the season [determines your reward](http://beta.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/features/announcing-end-season-3-rewards).

Answer (score 2):

In Season 2, you got the border based on the highest tier you achieved in about the last 6 weeks of the season.  If you got to gold 2 weeks before the end of Season 2, and then went back down to Silver, you still got the Gold border.  However, if you were in Gold earlier in the season and then went back down, you would have had to get back to Gold to get the gold border.

Riot hasn't directly addressed this issue for Season 3 as far as I am aware.  However, if they play by the same rules as Season 2, you will have to reach Gold tier again to get a gold border for Season 4.